# VPN и postgres. Не работает подключение

Tags: postgresql, vpn, cisco

Запускаю постгрес в докере.

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres"
    env_file:
      - ../${ENV_FILE}
    network_mode: host
```

При этом, работает Cisco Anyconnect security mobility client:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, со включёным впн, не работает подключение к постгресу. В чём причина?

Comment: может адреса совпали

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov аналогичная история и PyPi-registry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я подозреваю, что проблема в роутинге.

Большая часть VPN запускает роутинг всего трафика через VPN - подключение. То есть, если Вы вклчаете VPN, не настраивая VPN специальным образом, Вы теряете подключение к локальной сети. Ну, или к виртуальной сети.

у меня нет cisco - подключения, но для L2tp VPN отключить роутинг всего трафика через VPN можно таким образом: убирают галочку "Use default gateway on remote network". Возможно, в cisco VPN есть нечто похожее.

[image: картинка со свойствами подключения]

Comment: Что, неужели, совет помог?